# Getting error --- ImportError: cannot import name 'EMA' from 'backtesting.test'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create strategy EMA crossover
I installed backtesting via pip install backtesting

ImportError: cannot import name 'EMA' from 'backtesting.test'

But if I import SMA it works

So I guess backtesting I installed earlier does not have EMA ?
how do I import EMA than?

I searched on Google but did not find anything for EMA ..only for SMA I found and it works for SMA but I want to test crossover for EMA not SMA